# How to read a java map from request and iterate over it in a velocity template?

Tags: dictionary, jvm, liferay, liferay-6, velocity

Problem: I am working on Liferay 6.0.5. I want to read a java map from request and iterate over it in a velocity template. The velocity is not able to read it as map rather it is taken as String value.

JSP Code:
1. Reading categories:

```java
List<AssetCategory> curCategories = assetEntry.getCategories();
Map<String, String> catgrMap=new HashMap<String, String>();
String temp="";
String key=null;
for (AssetCategory category : curCategories) {
    key=(AssetVocabularyServiceUtil.getVocabulary(category.getVocabularyId())).getName();
    if(!temp.equalsIgnoreCase(key)){
       catgrMap.put(key,category.getName());
       temp=key;
    }else{
       String val=(String)catgrMap.get(key);
       val=val+","+category.getName();
       catgrMap.put(key,val);
       temp=key;
    }   
}
```

1. Setting Map in request

   ```
   request.setAttribute("categoryMap",catgrMap);
   ```

What I want: I want to iterate over this catgrMap and read its keys and values. Here is the steps:

1. Get map from request :

   ```
   #set ($categoryMap= $request.get('attributes').get('categoryMap'))
   ```
2. Iterate over map - There are many ways to iterate over a map in velocity and here are some of them.
   2.1

   ```
   #foreach ($mapEntry in $categoryMap.entrySet())
   <tr>
     <td>$mapEntry.key</td>
       <td>$mapEntry.value</td>
   ```

   #end

   ```
   2.2

   #set( $keys = $categoryMap.keySet() )
   ```

   #foreach( $key in $keys )
             
           $key
       $categoryMap[$key]
       
       #end

   ```
   2.3
   #set ($map = $categoryMap.getMap() )

   #foreach ($mapEntry in $map.entrySet())
   ```

   $mapEntry.key
       $mapEntry.value
       #end
3. The Roadblock: The problem is not how we are iterating, its how the velocity reads the map from request. It reads the map as String object so iteration is not possible. The ${categoryMap.class.name} returns String and not Map.

What are the possible ways to pass a map to velocity and iterate over it? We are not keen on using ext-plugin.

Comment: Why not pass the map through template context, as it is meant to be?

Comment: Is this is Liferay 6, which I'm assuming it as you mention ext-plugin, why not use the Plugins-SDK rather than do this in Velocity?

Comment: One question, where is this velocity located? Theme or Web Content Template? I've run into this issue as well and as far as I can remember, I believe what the $request is not the actual request object but actually just a Map<String, String>.

Comment: @RP - You are right, this is in web-content template. Can you guys post some code with reference to my post above? Though I have made it working using some workaround and playing with String classes but I will be happy to know right way from you guys.